# Using a Function Like foldl Recursively

Tags: haskell

As an exercise, I'm trying to write a function that behaves the same way as the foldl function and I'm trying to use recursion, as well.

My function will be called, "leftFolder" and the signature will look like a foldl function's:
 `leftFolder :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a`

I'm kinda stuck on what to do, but here's what I've tried:

```
leftFolder :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
leftFolder [] = []
leftFolder (x:xs) = x (++) (leftFolder xs)
```

In my mind, this makes sense. I'm saying that if the list is empty, return an empty list. If it's not, then take the head of the list and then keep appending it to the tail.

Comment: ... and what happens when you try this? (I suspect I can *guess*, but you should add that to your question!)

Comment: "If the list is empty, return an empty list." But I didn't want a list, I wanted to pick an `a`!

Comment: Recall that `foldl (+) 2 [3,4,5] = ((2+3)+4)+5`. How many arguments should your `leftFolder` take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of issues with your code. For example:

- you are pattern matchin as a first argument `[]` while the first argument should be a function
- you are using only 1 argument as opposed to the 3 you are requiring
- `x (++) ...` makes no sense; you probably meant to use `x:...`
- in the first pattern match you are returning a list, while the return type of your function is not necessarily a list

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
leftFolder :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
leftFolder _ c [] = c
leftFolder fn c (x:xs) = leftFolder fn (fn c x) xs
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a688512919a2b1c6)

That is: if the list is empty then we return the accumulated value in the second position. Otherwise we calculate the new accumulated value (`fn c x`) and then pass it as the second argument to our function while also forwarding `fn` and passing the rest of the list.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code here. So you are saying that we have this leftFolder function, and we will pass 3 arguments through it. The "_" indicates that we don't care what that argument will be and then the 2nd c argument indicates the starting point for the accumulator. The "[]" represents the empty list being passed through. I need help understanding the 3rd line. You are saying that we will pass a function argument (fn for stuff like (+) ) and an accumulator variable c, with a list with a head and tail. I need help understanding what's going on at "leftFolder fn (fn c x) xs"

Comment: `leftFolder fn (fn c x) xs` means apply the `leftFolder` function recursively on  following parameters: 1) the same `fn` function 2) the new accumulator created by applying the `fn` on the original accumulator `c` and the head of the list `x`, 3) tail of the list `xs` (the head element was processed, from left)

imho natural language sux in this case and `leftFolder fn (fn c x) xs` is more understandable